# Romania - Travel Non EU Citizen

Tags: visas, international-travel, paperwork, eu, romania

I am required to travel to Romania recently by my company for a business meeting.

I am currently a Pakistani National (Pakistani Passport), but also have the EU-Blue Card which is valid till 2020.

I would like to inquire if I need a visa to enter Romania, or do I need any other information.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if the travel is required by your company, then visa process should be their concern, not yours.

On the other hand, you should check [this](https://www.mae.ro/en/node/2040) site for information about visas to Romania. According to this page "Blue card" can be either

> The residence permit issued by a Schengen member state

or

> The long-term resident's EC residence permit (the validity of which is of 5 years or more) issued by a member state of the European Union.

If "Blue card" **fits** one of those conditions, you **don't need** an additional visa.

If you want to be 100% sure about visa the best way would be to call to the diplomatic mission of Romania in the country of your current residence & describe the situation.

Comment: Outdated info. A residence Permit **is** valid, full stop

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for passengers with a residence permit issued by Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus or a Schengen Member State for
>     a maximum stay of 90 days

A Blue card is a type of residence permit, so you do **not** need a visa.